# DIV position problem with the Flash object

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem in positioning the div on the flash object... the css for the div is:

```
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 100px;
    left: 200px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 234px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1000;
```

The position is OK when the opacity is 1... BUT it creates the problem when the opacity is less than 1 then it shows itself on the back of the flash object...

> Remember the WMODE of the flash object
>   is set to TRANSPARENT...

Any solution...?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved... Following is the solution... BUT first i want to mention the code which produced the problem...

```
<object align="" width="100%" height="200" id="charts" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
    <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
    <embed align="" width="100%" height="200" salign="TL" scale="noscale" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" swliveconnect="true" name="charts" style="background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" quality="high" src="/charts.swf?library_path=/charts_library&amp;xml_source=/chart&amp;license=">
        </object>
```

AND now the code which removed the problem... Just add the **wmode** to the emebed tag also...

```
<object align="" width="100%" height="200" id="charts" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
<param value="transparent" name="wmode">

    <embed align="" width="100%" height="200" salign="TL" scale="noscale" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" swliveconnect="true" name="charts" style="background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);" bgcolor="#E6E6E6" quality="high" src="/charts.swf?library_path=/charts_library&amp;xml_source=/chart&amp;license=" wmode="transparent">
    </object>
```